# php json_decode not working when pulling from file

Tags: php, json

I am pulling data from a weather api that only wants you to pull from the api not more than once every ten minutes, so I figured that I would save the json string to a file and save the time pulled to a file so I can compare current time to the last pull time and then either pull the data from the file or from the api. The if statement seems to work just fine. When the diff is over 600 it pulls the data from the api and displays the data, but when the diff is under 600 the array doesn't seem to be the same...

Any insight would be extremely appreciated!

```
function get_weather_data() {
    //define filepath to save/read/write weather data
    $weatherData = "";
    $weatherDataFile = "assets/docs/weather.json";

    //define filepath to save/read/write last api call time
    $prevTimeFile = "assets/docs/prevtime.txt";
    $prevTime = file_get_contents($prevTimeFile);
    $currTime = time();
    $diff = ($currTime - $prevTime);

    //If diff is longer than 10 mins (600 secs) then pull from api
    if ($diff < 600) { //get weather data from file
    $weatherData = file_get_contents($weatherDataFile);
    }
    else { //get weather data from api
    $request = ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=4699066&APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

    $weatherData = file_get_contents($request);

    //save api data back to weatherData file
    $wFile = fopen($weatherDataFile, "cb");
    fwrite($wFile, $weatherData);
    fclose($wFile);

    //save current time of data to prevTimeFile
    $tFile = fopen($prevTimeFile, "cb");
    fwrite($tFile, time() );
    fclose($tFile);
    }
    $weather = json_decode($weatherData, true);

    echo $diff;
    echo $weather['city']['name'];
}
```

Comment: If you do `var_dump($weatherData);`, what do you get?

Comment: What do you mean with "the array doesn't seem to be the same..."? Does the script crash? Do you get a result that is different from what you get from the API?

Comment: I get a string of the json returned

Comment: @jite No errors or script fail.  just nothing happens

Comment: have you looked in the json file? any contents? try adding `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the php file and see if there are any errors

Comment: @andrew The file definitely has the contents of the last pull. I'm already set in development mode in code igniter and no errors coming up

Comment: well, then I can only repeat the question by Jlite: What do you mean with "the array doesn't seem to be the same..."? also you really shouldn't publish your APPID, editing your question won't remove it, it will still be available in the history. You might want to consider deleting and re-posting

Comment: @andrew  My apologies, I guess that really doens't mean anything. I just don't get anything returned from the array when pulling from the file. And good catch, I didn't even think about the apid being in there.

Comment: Side note: No need to save the time in a separate file. Just call `filemtime` on the cached file.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I put the json data that was in the file into json lint and got an error... took me a min to figure out what happened, but I think that if the data pulled from the api is shorter than the previous data then it just leaves the old ending of the data tagged on thus making the json invalid. I either need to wipe the file before writing or only writing the data that I want in the first place to the file. Either way the input has helped tremendously!  Thanks all!